# retrieving a parameter from a string

Tags: php

```
index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=210&category_id=12&lang=is&limit=20&limitstart=180&page=shop.browse
```

and I would like to retrieve the **Page** parameter from the string and if that page parameter is equal to "**shop.browse**" than return a true boolean.

edit: ps. the string does not always look like this but it does always contain the page= parameter

Ive been messing with strpos function and others and I can't get this working and I need this code quickly so if anyone can point me in there right direction of the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting the url as a GET? or is this an url saved in a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) first to get just the query part, then use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) to get the values:

```
$query = parse_url($str,PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $match);
if ($match['page'] === 'shop.browse') {
    // page=shop.browse
}
```

Note that this assumes your string is stored in a variable `$str`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `parse_url()` function.

Answer (score 0):

the whole thing:

```
<?php

$url = "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=210&category_id=12&lang=is&limit=20&limitstart=180&page=shop.browse";
$url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url['query'], $output);
if($output['page'] == "shop.browse")
{
  //stmts
}
else
{
  //stmts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$str = explode("?",$url);

$str = explode("&",$str[1]);

foreach($str as $k=>$v) {

$xxx = explode("=",$v);

$output[$xxx[0]] = $output[$xxx[1]];

}

echo $output["page"];

this way you get all the parameters mapped to their keys. you obtain something like the $_GET/$_POST stuff is rendered.